# Numpy : What does this einsum expression mean and is there an alternative?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I understand following expression (A is an [200, 2] array) :

```
B = numpy.einsum('...i,...j->...ij',A，A)
```

And how to write it in another way not using `numpy.einsum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well that basically does element-wise multiplication between the elements along the last axis for `A` for all pairs. Now, since that `einsum` expression isn't doing any sum-reduction and is simply doing the job of [`broacasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we can avoid it by manually extending the input arrays to have one more dimension and let the broadcasting do its job. This would be more performant than using `einsum` and that's a good reason for look for an alternative to `einsum` for such a case.

The implementation for a `2D` and even a `n-dim` `A` (using the ellipsis notation) would be -

```
A[...,None,:]*A[...,None]
```

Sample run -

```
In [71]: A = np.random.rand(3,4,5,6)

In [72]: np.allclose(np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij',A,A), A[...,None,:]*A[...,None])
Out[72]: True
```

The performance aspect discussed earlier makes more sense, when the axis of expansion is of decent length. So, with `A` of shape `(200,2)` i.e. `2` as the axis length for the last axis, the improvement with extension of dims and using `broadcasting` would be less/not-at-all noticeable, but only seen with decent lengths. Let's verify these aspects -

```
In [76]: A = np.random.rand(20000,2)

In [77]: %timeit np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij',A,A)
1000 loops, best of 3: 207 µs per loop

In [78]: %timeit A[...,None,:]*A[...,None]
1000 loops, best of 3: 364 µs per loop

In [79]: A = np.random.rand(200,200)

In [80]: %timeit np.einsum('...i,...j->...ij',A,A)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.1 ms per loop

In [81]: %timeit A[...,None,:]*A[...,None]
100 loops, best of 3: 9.74 ms per loop
```